# User's location doesn't show on the map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapbox

I downloaded MapBox Me. User location doesn't show on the map. Property `mapView.isUserLocationVisible` is `YES`. `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`. But I don't see blue circle or dot on the map. What should I do to make it visible?

Answer (score 3):

Setting `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES` will add the blue dot to the map automatically. If you want to center on the blue dot to move it on screen, you want `mapView.userTrackingMode`.

Answer (score 1):

Without much more information (starting with the code you're using), it's impossible to know exactly why you are having trouble displaying the user's location on a map.

Simply setting the property Map.showsUserLocation is not enough to show the user's position.

Answer (score 1):

The current location (RMUserLocation) is an extension of RMAnnotation.  If you want to show your location you'd put it on the map like any other notation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for a second, but did see the RMUserLocation show up once GPS was available in the layerForAnnotation-method, but still not drawn on the map.

One possible cause is that you're trying to draw a marker for the user location.

Try adding this code:

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    //Show the user location
    if( [annotation isKindOfClass:[RMUserLocation class]] )
        return nil;
    .... run your own code
}
```

Solved it for me.